# BATCH - netstat command in IF statement

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, netstat

```
SET con = netstat -a -n | find "127.0.0.1:3306"
if "%con%" == "" (
    telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
)
pause
```

This will always execute telnet.

Actually when I look manually for `netstat -a -n | find "127.0.0.1:3306"` it isn't equal to `""` but `%con%` is always set to `""`, why?.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You're confusing the Windows shell with a useful Linux shell.

Comment: Yeah, obviously I AM am a Linux user :D And that's why I need help. Windows Shell does always confusing my logic..

Comment: `SET con = netstat -a -n | find "127.0.0.1:3306"` set a variable named `"con "` (with the space after) to a value `' netstat -a -n | find "127.0.0.1:3306"'` (with space before). It doesn't execute the command. You don't have any `%con%` but `%con %`, therefore printing `%con%` will give you an empty string

Comment: Yes, as I said Windows seems confusing to me. @LinuxDisciple solution helped me out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try something like this instead.

```
netstat -a -n |find "127.0.0.1:3306" >nul
if ERRORLEVEL 1 (
telnet 127.0.0.1 3306
)
```

Your approach looks like a generic Linux shell solution, but Windows batch is nowhere near as useful or flexible.

The approach above uses the return code from 'find' to determine whether or not to run telnet.

One thing that messed me up for a while is that `ERRORLEVEL <number>` works like `ERRORLEVEL GE <number>` *not* `ERRORLEVEL EQ <number>`, so `ERRORLEVEL 0` is always true.

Comment: you can use `if %errorlevel%==1` for equality. NT cmd also supports other comparison operators

Comment: even in Linux it's recommended to use `$?` instead of checking the variable value like that, except when you need to use the variable later